# Wcf serialisation exclude defaults

Tags: wcf

I seem to remember th ere being an attribute which will tell the serialiser to not include a field if it has a default value, or possibly just null.

Can anyone remember if such a thing exists in wcf?

Comment: Which serializer are you asking about?

Comment: Excellent point Hugh, DataContractSerializer, although I think I saw the "do not serialise if default or null" was declared via an attribute. I'm guessing a WCF compliant serializer would have to understand the common attributes like [DataMember] ? haven't actually given that much thought.

Comment: I definitely can't find it in the DataContractSerializer docs, so I'm starting to think it was not standard. Contextually I remember seeing it within Microsoft documentation though which is partly why I expected it to be standard :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Data Contract Serializer you can use the EmitDefaultValue property:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string position = null;
```

Comment: Spot on thank you. I'm trying to figure out why I couldn't find that earlier, besides sloppy googling. Might help find thigns in future.